Azure pipeline - powershell variables are not accessible between steps
I am creating a pipeline and for some reason I can't access variables between steps.
Everything is included within one job. I tried the isOutput=true flague, I also tried accessing variables by specifying their step name first but still did not work - see token01 at the end with error message as a comment.
Here is my code:
trigger:
- master

jobs:
- job: RunTests
  pool:
    name: 'some_name'

  steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'some_subscription'
      scriptType: 'ps'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
         $password = az keyvault secret show --name "some_name123" --vault-name "keyvault_name" --query value -o tsv
         Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SECRET_PASSWORD]$password"
  - powershell: |
      $env:SECRET_PASSWORD = "$(SECRET_PASSWORD)"
      cd src/AutomatedTests/PlaywrightTests
      npm install --verbose
      npm list --verbose
      npx playwright install chromium
      npx playwright test tests/getTokens.spec.js --project=chromium --reporter=list | tee playwright-output.log
      Get-Location
      $logContent = Get-Content "playwright-output.log" -Raw
      $token01 = ''
      $token02 = ''

      foreach ($line in $logContent) {
          if ($line -match 'TOKEN01:([^\s]+)') {
              $token01 = $matches[1]
              Write-Host "Found TOKEN01: $token01"
          }
          if ($line -match 'TOKEN02:([^\s]+)') {
              $token02 = $matches[1]
              Write-Host "Found TOKEN02: $token02"
          }
      }

      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token01;isOutput=true]$token01"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token02;isOutput=true]$token02"
    name: GetTokens
    displayName: 'test'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: 'src/AutomatedTests/PlaywrightTests/playwright-output.log'
      artifactName: 'PlaywrightLogs' 
      publishLocation: 'Container'

  - powershell: |
      newman -v
      Write-Host "Token01: $(token01)" #token01 : The term 'token01' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
      Write-Host "Token02: $(token02)"
 

 


Consider using the Azure Key vault task to retrieve secrets, instead of doing it programmatically.

On the PowerShell task (name: GetTokens) you set the token01 and token02 as two output variables.
Within the same job, you should use the expression "$(taskName.varName)" to access the output variables. So, on the subsequent tasks, you should access the output variables like as below.
steps:
. . .

- powershell: |
    . . .
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token01;isOutput=true]$token01"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token02;isOutput=true]$token02"
  name: GetTokens
  displayName: 'test'

. . .

- powershell: |
    newman -v
    Write-Host "Token01: $(GetTokens.token01)" 
    Write-Host "Token02: $(GetTokens.token02)"

For more details, see the documentation "Use output variables from tasks".

Have you tried as the suggestion in this answer? Does your pipeline can work as expected now? @panigale

Thank you Bright Ran-MSFT, your solution worked well.
